# How to get a WPF DataGrid cell to right align without making the selectable area on a new row tiny?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using a WPF4.0 DataGrid. When double clicking on a cell in a new row everything works fine **unless** I've added a cell style to that column. For example, I have a numeric column where I want the data right aligned so the xaml looks like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ImpaId}"
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource CellRightAlign}">
     <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
          <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}">Impa</TextBlock>
     </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Where the style in a shared resource is just:

```
<Style x:Key="CellRightAlign">
    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

The resulting selectable area on a new row is shown in the image as that small blue area.This is a very small target for the user to hit, and this happens to be the most likely column they will want to start with on a new row.

[image: DataGrid cell with tiny width]

If I remove the CellStyle, the area works as desired but of course I lose the right alignment.

[image: DataGrid cell with proper width]

Does anyone know how to achieve both?

**Things I tried**

1. Setting TargetNullValue on the binding to a format with some width.
   This works on existing rows but has no effect on a new row.
2. Setting MinWidth on the column, this did not affect the width of the new row selectable
   area.

**Thing that worked:**

Using the information from the answer by @AngelWPF I was able to change from using CellStyle to using ElementStyle as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ImpaId}"
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource CellRightAlign}">
```

Became

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ImpaId}"
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellRightAlign}">
```

Comment: Similar problem but don't know the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378515/how-to-make-cell-to-take-full-width-when-aligned-to-right-or-left-in-wpf-grid

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You could apply `ElementStyle` on the `DataGridTextColumn` targetted to `TextBlock` and right align that, it would work.

```
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ImpaId}">
          <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
               <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource
                                  DataGridHeader}">
                    Impa
               </TextBlock>
          </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
          <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
              </Style>
          </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I was able to minimize the code by just adding the ElementStyle property at the outer DataGridTextColumn and have it use my existing CellRightAlign. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Just wanted to add to more examples for future code searches.

I put this in the top of the xaml file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Included, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then in the datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Excluded" Binding="{Binding Excluded}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightCell}"/>
```

This right aligns the text and sorting is still enabled. The textbox fills the cell and in this case is colored using a bool converter.

Comment: Perfect and simple "ElementStyle" assignment.

Comment: This also fixes an issue where pressing Tab would cause a "pause" between columns, thanks a lot genius

Answer (score 6):

You can try a work around :

```
           <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=ImpaId}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar problem and found another solution by overwriting the Style for the DataGridCell in Blend.

The changed items from the original style are the setters for `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` in the Style itself to stretch the cell itself and `VerticalAlignment="Center"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` in the Template property to align the content. Change these values to whatever you need to align the cells content.

The rest of the style *could* be removed so that the settings from the base style will be used (using the StaticResource the style is BasedOn). However I left the style as Blend produced it.

This resulting XAML-Code should then be included into the controls resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

    <!-- Additional styles, can be removed to fall back to base styles -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=FocusBorderBrushKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and got it solved now. If you want to do it inside the c# code, you need to set a bunch of setters:

```
DataGridTextColumn numColumn = new DataGridTextColumn
Style s = new Style();
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right));
numColumn.CellStyle = s;
```