# right to left support for data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid

How is it possible to set direction of `GridView` in WPF `RightToLeft`:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gvMembers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="297" Width="580"/>
```

It is left to right by default.

Comment: Should try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7803685/1714342 , should help :)

Comment: i mean dategrid direction not cells direction @wudzik

Comment: doesn't `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` work on the `DataGrid` for you?

Comment: thx viv , exactly i wanted this attribute , Send Answer to accept it

Comment: How to RTL a cell ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`

Answer (score -1):

use this 
   dgvActivity.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;

dgvActivity is the name of datagrideview