# How to make cell to take full width when aligned to right or left in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grid-layout

I'm designing some grid in WPF and want to display numbers aligned to right, but when I set HorizontalAlignment=Right the cell itself don't use all available width, so the border is painted half based on content. Look at the attached picture.

[image]

The code is:

```
<Grid Width="620" Name="tblTaxBalance">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" Style="{StaticResource CellRightAlign}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" Style="{StaticResource CellRightAlign}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- row 1 -->
    <Label Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="1">Тайлангийн төрөл</Label>
    <Label Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">Татварын төрөл</Label>
    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">Эцсийн үлдэгдэл /мян. төг/</Label>

    <!-- row 2 -->
    <Label Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Дутуу</Label>
    <Label Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">Илүү</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show your Style CellAlignRight?

Comment: You can ignore CellAlignRight, it has HorizontalAlignment="Right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HorizontalAlignment Stretch and set FlowDirection RightToLeft

Like that:

```
<Label Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TaxTableCellStyle}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">Дутуу</Label>
```

Comment: Thanks, FlowDirection="RightToLeft" fixed all the problems.